# Lose mount with external folder

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba

I have a project that run in a virtual linux server, when a user upload a file, the server store it in a folder in other windows server.

To connect the server I had modify the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//SRV-STORAGE/server-folder/ /home/internal-folder cifs credentials=/etc/samba/credential,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

In `/etc/samba/crendential` I have set the crediantal for external folder.

For a few time it run without problem, but randomically the upload of the file don't run, remain unsettled, and it's necessary to restart the application.

There are a method to resolve this problem?

The only way is to create a script that reconnect the two server?

Thanks in advance